# PHPs gettext with directory of languages without textdomain

Tags: php, gettext, php-gettext

I want to use PHPs gettext() to translate my application automatically. But for me, it's real overkill having `locales/de_DE/LC_ALL/$app_name.mo`.
I would need somnthing like only `locales/de_DE.mo`, like WordPress does it. How could I configure gettext to use it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is: you can't.

Long answer: Wordpress doesn't rely on gettext. It uses the same po/mo input files, but mimics `gettext` behavior with its own classes and functions, basically storing translations in a global array.

You can see this looking at the source code of `/wp-includes/l10n.php` and every class inside of `wp-includes/pomo`